# `does not name a type` help, 10.6.8, using 10.4u SDK

Tags: c++, macos, types, compiler-errors, adobe

I have an XCode project that works by itself. I am trying to integrate what it does into a new project that is inclusive with the rest of our products. I am getting errors like:

```
'uint8' does not name a type

'uint16' does not name a type

'uint32' does not name a type
```

but I am not sure why. It is being used as:

```
typedef uint8 SPUInt8;
typedef uint16 SPUInt16;
typedef uint32 SPUInt32;
```

I cannot find what is wrong. I am using the same headers and source as the original project. I have been over the build settings to make sure they match.

I thought it might be SDL.h but that doesn't exist on OSX. I have also tried including

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
```

in the new project but the old project doesn't include them

This is a CS5 64-bit photoshop plugin using the Adobe SDK.

Comment: Why aren't you using the standard types `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, etc?

Comment: @trojanfoe: The question states that existing code is being integrated into a new project. Thus, the reason the person asking the question is using these types is because the code contains it. You could ask why they were used originally, but the author of that code is not directly available.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Or easier still, globally change all the non-standard types to standard ones...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These types are defined in the OpenCL framework (specifically in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cl_kernel.h) and the Security framework (specifically in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Headers/cssmconfig.h). I do not know why they are in these particular frameworks.

Adding this line to your source file will define the types:

```
#include <Security/Security.h>
```

Does your source code appear to use the APIs in the Security framework? Or OpenCL?

Comment: no we dont use either of those frameworks. This is a project based upon the Adobe SDK